# BigQuery Partition according to Category

Tags: google-bigquery

Need some help in solving this.
Say There is a table x with 2 fields -> order number and category.
For a single order number, there can be more than one category (max kind is 3 say).

tx_num Category

1234   blade

1234  razor

12345 blade

12345 book

123456 blade

1234 book

I want to return something like this using big query

tx_num   type

1234 contains blade, razor, book

12345 contains blade and book

123456 contains only blade

Comment: tx_num and order number are one and the same

Comment: got a solution using string_agg function! Let me know if you guys got any other solutions!!! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below si for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select tx_num, 
  'contains ' || string_agg(Category, ', ') type
from `project.dataset.table`
group by tx_num
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]